# Rewriting url with Application Request Routing (MVC5 application)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, url-rewriting, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 application with url *http://site1.com* running in IIS on an integrated application pool. I have another service running on *http://site2.com/dir/service.svc*.

I am trying to create a rewrite rule for *http://site1.com/dir/service.svc* to go to *http://site2.com/dir/service.svc*.

I keep getting *404 NOT FOUND* responses. But I have verified that I can browse the service through my web browser.

In IIS, I've used the ARR (*Application Request Routing*) plugin to create rewrite rules on both the application and the server level.

The following is an example of the rewrite rule from both applicationHosts.config (server level) and web.config (application level):

```
<rule name="rewrtite test 2" patternSyntax="ExactMatch">
  <match url="http://site1.com/dir/service.svc" />
  <action type="Rewrite" url="http://site2.com/dir/service.svc" />
</rule>
```

In my MVC application, I have tried to add the following to my *RouteConfig.cs*:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("dir/{*pathInfo}");
```

I also tried with:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("dir/service.svc");
```

I read that the problem might be because of *ExtensionlessUrlHandler* so I tried removing it with:

```
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
</handlers>
```

Some details:

- IIS 6.2
- MVC 5
- .NET 4.5.1

I've tried to turn on *FailedRequestLogging* with the following settings:

- All Content (*)
- Status Codes: 200-600
- Providers: ASP, ASP.NET, ISAPI Extension, WWW Server

But I don't get any log files in *%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\FailedReqLogFiles*.

Thanks.

Comment: I found that I can use RegEx matching, and rewrite the rule to _site2.com/dir/{R:1}_. But I do not wish to expose all services on _site2.com/dir/_. Still stuck, but somewhat progress.

Comment: Found another solution to my problem. But if anyone out there know how to solve this, please share! :)